# Interface property be of the type of a different interface property

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

So I am trying to coordinate two separate interfaces in an instance of a table, a table which I would like to make filtering optional so I started with two interfaces for this (leaving out the rest of the implementation). One to hold data about the columns and one to hold the data of the filtering

```
interface Column {
  headerTitle: string;
  headerId: string;
}

interface Filter {
  filteredHeaderIds: string []; // I would like this to be of type of headerId
  noDataMessage: string;
}
```

In the implementation above, I would want `filterHeaderIds` to be tied to whatever the user implements as a part of the `Column`.
Example:

```
const columns: Column[] = [{
  headerTitle: 'Person Name',
  headerId: 'name',
}, {
  headerTitle: 'Person Age',
  headerId: 'age',
}];

const filterData: Filter = {
  filteredHeaderIds: ['name','throwError'], 
  noDataMessage: 'No Data Found',
}
```

Since `throwError` isn't a defined `headerId` I would like to see if it's possible to have typescript throw an error. Is something like this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types). This would only be a valid solution if you are saying that your column definitions would be part of compiled code:

```
type ColumnHeaderId = 'name' | 'age';

interface Column {
  headerTitle: string;
  headerId: ColumnHeaderId;
}

interface Filter {
  filteredHeaderIds: ColumnHeaderId[];
  noDataMessage: string;
}
```

However, if you are wanting the columns to be completely dynamically generated, I think you'll be stuck with implementing run-time logical checking for ID fields matching.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yeah I kind of see the flaw in that it would be a run time check for typescript because it would be on each instance of the interfaces and you have no way to relate them.